# angular 8 routerLink is not properly working in ios device browsers

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, iphone, typescript

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isRouterEntry">
    <a [ngClass]="(node.HaveModules == 0)?'secondlevel':'thirdlevel'"
    mat-menu-item routerLink="{{node.FormName}}" routerLinkActive="active" target="_blank">  
        <span class="menuname responsivefont" style="font-size: 13px;color: #b7c0cd;">
            {{node.MenuName}}
        </span>
    </a>
</ng-container>
```

> I try to navigate thru the router link but it does not work in mac device browser but it is properly working in windows and android devices.

Comment: Can you give some more information as to what does it mean "not properly working". is there an error? What are your configuration?

Comment: are you using "routerLink" with target="_blank"? the idea of a SPA is execute an app in the same "session". Try using simply ´<a>´

Comment: it is working properly the issue is in my emulator